# Flickr plugin that will display photos from multiple group pools?

Tags: plugins, widgets, flickr, images, sidebar

Does anyone know of a WordPress plugin that will pull in photos from multiple flickr group pools, and display random thumbnails in the sidebar?

There are a ton of flickr plugins, and I just can't seem to find one that'll support multiple group pools.
Something that will accept multiple rss feeds and display pictures from all of them would also be acceptable.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Flickr; what specifically are "group pools?"  Can you give some example URLs that you want to pull from?  Also, you can list the Flickr plugins you've tried including links to them so we can look at them for you? Maybe one of them only needs a small modification?

Comment: not so that flicks plugin wordpress junkie, but isn't there one that handles one group? This might be a start, since the functionality is in, should be easy to extend. So if you have something to play around with, please link.

Answer (score 2):

[Flickr Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/flickr-gallery/other_notes/) is WordPress plugin that goes beyond the basics and allows several options for searching and displaying Flickr photos. I couldn't tell from your question, but if you want to display each group separately (*i.e.*, a set of thumbnails from Group 1 next to a set of thumbnails from Group 2), then this will do the trick.

On the other hand, if you want to combine the thumbnails from two or more groups into a common list, it is very unlikely that you will find a plugin to do this out of the box, and the reason is this: The Flickr API does not provide for searching multiple groups simultaneously (neither the [basic search](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html) nor the [group-pool–specific search](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.groups.pools.getPhotos.html)). The only way to make this happen is to aggregate the RSS feeds as Mike Lee described or use the API and combine the search results programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I know of no such plugin either. Other than creating your own (which I'm guessing you want to avoid), you could consider this hack:

- Get the RSS feed for each Flickr group
- Use [Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) to aggregate & randomize those RSS feeds
- Plug the RSS output into any one of those Flickr plugins you've seen

Yahoo! Pipes takes a bit of playing around, but once you have it, it works wonderfully. Hope this helps.

Comment: yahoo pipe rocks when you combine that with YQL.